# Kivy FileChooser como selecionar um diretório

Tags: python, python-kivy, kivy

Preciso criar uma interface onde o usuário possa selecionar um diretório, meu código:

```
class MainScreen(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        b1 = Button(text='iniciar',
        pos_hint={'x':.375, 'y':.65}, size_hint=(.25, .05))
        t1 = TextInput(pos_hint={'x':.375, 'y':.55}, size_hint=(.25, .05))
        t2 = TextInput(pos_hint={'x':.375, 'y':.45}, size_hint=(.25, .05))
        t3 = TextInput(pos_hint={'x':.375, 'y':.35}, size_hint=(.25, .05))
        l1 = Label(text='Entrada:', pos_hint={'x':.375, 'y':.60}, size_hint=(.25, .05))
        l2 = Label(text='Saida:', pos_hint={'x':.375, 'y':.50}, size_hint=(.25, .05))
        l3 = Label(text='Objeto:',pos_hint={'x':.375, 'y':.40}, size_hint=(.25, .05))
        i1 = Image(source='logoheader.png', pos_hint={'x':.600, 'y':.10}, size_hint=(.35, .1))
        b2 = Button(text='Select',
        pos_hint={'x':.640, 'y':.55}, size_hint=(.05, .05))
        b2.bind(on_press = self.fc)
        b3 = Button(text='Select',
        pos_hint={'x':.640, 'y':.45}, size_hint=(.05, .05))
        b4 = Button(text='Select',
        pos_hint={'x':.640, 'y':.35}, size_hint=(.05, .05))

        self.add_widget(b1)
        self.add_widget(t1)
        self.add_widget(t2)
        self.add_widget(t3)
        self.add_widget(l1)
        self.add_widget(l2)
        self.add_widget(l3)
        self.add_widget(i1)
        self.add_widget(b2)
        self.add_widget(b3)
        self.add_widget(b4)


    def fc(self, button):
        floatlayout = FloatLayout()
        b1 = Button(text='Selecionar', size_hint=(.5, .1), pos_hint={'x':.0, 'y':.005})
        b2 = Button(text='Cancelar', size_hint=(.5, .1), pos_hint={'x':.5, 'y':.005})
        fc1 = FileChooserIconView(size_hint=(1, .9), pos_hint={'x':0, 'y':.12})

        floatlayout.add_widget(b1)
        floatlayout.add_widget(b2)
        floatlayout.add_widget(fc1)

        popup = Popup(content=(floatlayout))
        popup.open()



class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainScreen()

MainApp().run()
```

O problema é que o kivy abre automaticamente as pastas sempre que você clica nelas, diferente do windows por exemplo onde o primeiro click seleciona o arquivo e o segundo entra no diretório, como eu poderia mudar isso ? Pois tenho um botão selecionar que está pronto para receber uma função assim que o usuário tiver selecionado uma pasta.

Essa é minha janela da interface no momento:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E aqui o que acontece após um click único em alguma pasta:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a propriedade `dirselect`:

https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.filechooser.html#kivy.uix.filechooser.FileChooserController.dirselect

```
fc1 = FileChooserIconView(size_hint=(1, .9), pos_hint={'x':0, 'y':.12}, dirselect=True)
```